# Want to Minimise Browser Dependence

Tags: website-design, looking-for-a-script, looking-for-similar

I am a web administrator to the site [Nrityakalamandiram](http://www.nrityakalamandiram.in)

In the long run, I want the site's appearance not to conspicuously vary from browser to browser. I would like my site to appear and function exactly as I want it to, at least in the most popular browsers like Firefox, IE, Chrome, Chromium.

As a step toward this I would like to get one thing sorted out

See http://www.nritykalamandiram.in/home/gallery.html

I opened it in Firefox, the album name "THE DIRECTOR" is just above the black box in which the photo gallery lies:

[image: Appearance in Firefox Browser]

I opened it in Chromium, the same page appears thus:

[image: Appearance in Chromium Browser]

What I have done as follows: Inside a  element I have written the album name as per user's click (on the left side is a list of albums) and below it, displayed the gallery box. The mother  is intended to be transparent like. To achieve this I appended "background-color:transparent" to the "style" property of

This is ineffective in Firefox but not in Chromium as one sees - in the latter picture attached - a white patch to the left and above the gallery box!

It is evident from above that

```
    <div style="background-color:transparent..." ... >
```

does not serve the purpose uniformly for all browsers.

I am perhaps too fussy about a seemingly negligible aberration such as this, but somehow the white patches are jarring.

In light of the above I have a question:

Is there a code that achieves the transparency of the mother  as described above, uniformly for all popular browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way chrome treats iframes, since you are embedding an iframe it is giving the HTML/BODY a white background by default and this is inherited.

You should opt to embed the gallery without an iframe and then you can properly style this element.

Comment: You mean I should do it without <frame> element?

Comment: I scanned through all the stack exchange websites and found that this was the site that I felt my question would fit in! Now that you marked a question as off-topic, down-voted it, I would be thankful to astronomical levels, if you kindly suggest where questions relating to HTML coding, Server Scripting fit.

Comment: Why do you accuse bybe of downvoting your question without evidence?